# How to create a threshold in highcharts ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a simple line chart with highchart ng the problem is that I cannot set the threshold to zero the threshold property according to the [highcharts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.threshold) should be **plotoption.series.threshold** also according to this a[nswer it should be under plotoptions](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/432) but as you can see in my jsfiddle it seems [not to work for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/2dq6ysg9/3/) what I want here to do is to move the x-axis to the point 0 where all the negative values show after the x-axis

code:

```
 $scope.highchartsNG = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      },
      plotOptions: {
      line: {

      },
        series: {
          threshold: 3
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [10, 15, 12, 8, -7]
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do with plot Options see here

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                threshold:0,
                 negativeColor: 'green'
            }
        },
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2dq6ysg9/3/)**

You can try using plotLines for x-axis,

```
yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'dBmV'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'green'
            }]
        },
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pr9u0w48/)**